# push notification in ExtJS

Tags: html, extjs, push-notification

I am developing a HTMl5 based application using ExtJS. The server is pushing messages whenever updates comes. In this app, I have to implement push notification (instead set timer to get updated messages from server periodically).

Is there way to implement push notification using ExtJS or using any JavaScript framework?

--Sridhar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use WebSocket technology for this purpose which allows a server and an ExtJS client communicate over a full-duplex TCP connection. Here is an ExtJS WebSocket component: https://github.com/wilk/ExtJS-WebSocket

It also provides event-driven communication and message broadcasting to multiple peers which exactly fits the requirements of implementing push notiication.